# Bound on the integral of a function with multiple zeros

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

This is a follow-up to this  [If $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=0$, $\forall x, \exists c, f(x)=\frac{1}{6}x(x-1)(x-2)f'''(c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297109/if-f0-f1-f2-0-forall-x-exists-c-fx-frac16xx-1x-2fc)

> Let $f:[0,2]\to \mathbb R$ be a $C^3$ function such that $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=0$
>
> a. Prove that $\forall x\in[0,2], \exists c\in[0,2], f(x)=\frac{1}{6}x(x-1)(x-2)f'''(c)$
>
> b. Prove that $\displaystyle \int_0^2|f|\leq \frac{1}{12} \sup_{t\in[0,2]} |f'''(t)|$
>
> c. Let $M=\sup_{t\in[0,2]}f'''$ and $m=\inf_{t\in[0,2]}f'''$.
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle \left| \int_0^2f\right|\leq \frac{M-m}{24}$

While b. follows directly from a., I haven't been able to prove c.

Since $x\to \frac{1}{6}x(x-1)(x-2)$ oscillates over $[0,2]$, I tried to get different bounds of $\int_0^1f$ and $\int_1^2 f$, but that doesn't yield the desired inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, part (c) is false (as Alex Ravsky shows). Suppose we change the definitions to: 
\begin{align} 
&M = \sup_{t\in [0,2]} f'''(t)\\
&m = \inf_{t\in[0,2]} f'''(t)
\end{align} 
Then part (c) can be proven from part (b) by defining $h(x) = f(x) - cx(x-1)(x-2)$ for a suitable value of $c$ such that $h'''(x) \in [-(M-m)/2, (M-m)/2]$ for all $x \in [0,2]$.

Comment: This is how the problem was stated indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Without additional assumptions (for instance, that some derivative of the function $f$ is bounded at $[0,2]$ by a given constant), the bound (c) does not hold, because for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $C^3$ function $f:[0,2]\to [0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=0$, but $f(x)=1$ for each $x\in [0,2]\setminus ([0,\varepsilon)\cup (1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)\cup (2-\varepsilon,2])$.

Comment: I agree.  However, I suspect that definitions were intended to be $M = \sup_{t \in [0,2]} f'''(t)$ and $m = \inf_{t\in[0,2]} f'''(t)$.  In that case part (c) can be prove from part (b).

Comment: I'm sorry I posted a flawed statement. Michael got the proof I needed.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM It's ok, nevermind.